# C# Excel: The copied sheet is 50x larger than the original one

Tags: c#, excel, copy, paste

I used C# to copy and paste a Worksheet of Excel. (I used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for this)

This is the code:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[4];
Range us = ws.UsedRange;
us.Copy();
Worksheet ws2 = wb.Worksheets.Add();
ws2.Paste();
wb.SaveAs(Filename: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + copyName + ".xlsx");
wb.Close();
```

And when I open the xlsx file as a zip, the copied sheet is 50 times larger than the one I copied from.

Here is an image: (sheet1 is the copied sheet, and sheet2 is the original sheet)
[image: The large files]

Is there a way to copy and paste without making the sheet large?

(I need to paste 300 times. And after I paste that sheet 300 times, the file is about 500MB! And I cannot even open the file because it's too big.)

Comment: is the original sheet an .xsl or .xlsx?

Comment: Did you view the XML and compare it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't `Copy` the worksheet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why. I need to copy the whole worksheet, not the used range.